# GET request format using mongoose and angular

Tags: angularjs, mongodb, express, http-get

In regard to the getRooms function, I expected to console.log, on partial page load (/rooms) , an array of objects containing roomName, moderator, and description as outlined by my mongoose model (Room) and data in the db, so that I could render some of this information to the page. Instead I am console logging what appears to be my index.html code as response on the client side and the server is never reached. My POST and PUT requests are working, and although this is rudimentary, it seems I am not understanding how to properly go about making this GET request. If someone could inform me as to how this is done properly, I would appreciate it.

```
//roomController.js
    angular.module('chatApp').controller('roomController', ['$scope','$http','$location', '$cookies', function($scope, $http, $location, $cookies){

    // $scope.rooms = [
    //   {'name': 'Biology', 'description': 'Discuss the wonders of Bio'},
    //   {'name': 'Literature', 'description': 'From Steinbeck to Shakespeare'},
    //   {'name': 'Dark Souls 3', 'description': 'Discuss gameplay from DS3'},
    //   {'name': 'The Life of Pablo', 'description': "Discuss Kanye West\'s the Life of Pablo"},
    //   {'name': 'Daredevil', 'description': 'Discuss the Netflix original Daredevil'},
    //   {'name': 'React JS', 'description': 'Discuss ReactJS projects'}
    // ];


  $scope.getRooms = function(){
      $http.get('/rooms').then(function(response){
        $scope.roomCount = response.data.length;
        console.log(response.data.length);
        console.log(response);
      });

  };

  $scope.createRoom = function(){
    var newRoom = {
      roomName: $scope.roomName,
      moderator: $cookies.get('currentUser'),
      description: $scope.roomDescription
    };
    $http.post('/createRoom', newRoom).then(function(){
      $scope.roomName = '';
      $scope.moderator = '';
      $scope.description = '';

      $location.path('/createRoom');

      bootbox.alert('Sucessfully created Room.');
    });
  };


}]);


//server side route
//get rooms 

app.get('/rooms', function(req,res){
  Room.find({}, function (err, rooms) {
        res.send(rooms);
        console.log(rooms);
      });
    });


//relevant part of partial page
    <div class="container-fluid" id="roomsPage" data-ng-init="getRooms()">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check your serverside routes. youre logging the index.html page because your request isnt hitting any express routes. so instead it hits the app.get(*) route and its returning the html of your index.html page. make sure everything is spelled right and youre using a get on the other end instead of a post unless you mean to

Comment: yes, looks like both are GET and everything seems to be spelled correctly, anything else look wrong?

Comment: does your * route happen before your /rooms route on your server?